# Show 35k items in time line diagram with SAP VizFrame / d3.js (Performance)

Tags: d3.js, sapui5

I want to present my large time series dataset with approximately 35000 items in my time series line chart. I use the SAP UI5 VizChart which builds on d3.js.

The performance for this large dataset is very bad. Every time I want to zoom and navigate the application hangs for a few seconds.

The VizFrame loads the complete dataset, although I don't net it every time, because my section is much smaller. But if I want to have an overall overview, is there any way to display the diagram correctly without integrating all 35k data points? Mathematical? d3.js method?

I get the data via an odata service. Would it be sufficient if I hang a limit parameter or similar to the odata url? Thanks!

Edit: I have to use the VizFrame which based on d3.js but I don't know how I could use d3 methods directly. The documentations of VizFrame are very bad...

[VizFrame API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame.html)

[Chart Property References](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/vizdocs/index.html#reference/chartProperty/Charts/Line%20%20(3)/Line%20Chart%20for%20Date/Time%20Series/)

Comment: You need to figure out how to cut down your data loaded to just what you are visualizing. And then you need to use smoothing or something else to bring that down to a reasonable number of data points to visualize (your screen is not 35k pixels wide, so you aren't visualizing 35k unique items anyway). If VizChart/VizFrame doesn't support this, then perhaps look at different solutions. The OpenUI5 Slack may also be a good place to ask.